# How to set headers in Cordova InAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, http-headers, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

In an app I'm building using the [ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) (based on [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)) I'm using the [Cordova InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) to visit a url, but I want to set custom headers for that request. I've read over the readme and some other sites, but I can't find anything.

Does anybody know how I can set headers in the Cordova InAppBrowser? All tips are welcome!

Comment: is there any updated answer for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I now know this could not be done. So I opted for an alternative solution in which I gave the params via the url. I could do this because I also controlled the url which I wanted to open. So it worked, but it wasn't ideal.

Anyway, maybe this can help other people.